# How to write the output of an executable binary into memory rather than disk

Tags: linux, bash, go

I got a binary that works like the below:

```
> ./my_bin raw.avi output_file.avi
```

`output_file.avi` is what I want, some verbose information will print in the terminal when the job is succeeded, like:

> Copyright 2022 Company Inc... Success.

I want to run this command inside my code and redirect the `output_file.avi` into some byte array so that I don't have to read it from disk and delete it. My approach looks like the below Golang snippet:

```
func wrongOne(stdin []byte) ([]byte, error) {
    inBuf := bytes.NewBuffer(stdin)
    outBuf := bytes.NewBuffer(nil)
    cmd := exec.Command("./my_bin", "/dev/stdin", "/dev/stdout")
    cmd.Stdin = inBuf
    cmd.Stdout = outBuf
    err := cmd.Run()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return outBuf.Bytes(), nil // wrong
}
```

However, the return byte array is longer than the below approach, which leads to failure on the MD5 check.

```
func correctOne(stdin []byte) ([]byte, error) {
    inBuf := bytes.NewBuffer(stdin)
    cmd := exec.Command("./my_bin", "/dev/stdin", "output_file")
    cmd.Stdin = inBuf
    err := cmd.Run()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return os.ReadFile("output_file")
}
```

the `wrongOne` function can be modified to following code to be correct:

```
func modifiedWrongOne(stdin []byte) ([]byte, error) {
    inBuf := bytes.NewBuffer(stdin)
    outBuf := bytes.NewBuffer(nil)
    cmd := exec.Command("./my_bin", "/dev/stdin", "/dev/stdout")
    cmd.Stdin = inBuf
    cmd.Stdout = outBuf
    err := cmd.Run()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    correct, _ := correctOne(stdin)
    return outBuf.Bytes()[:len(correct)], nil // diff
}
```

I presume that the output verbose information is included in the `/dev/stdout` so that the `wrongOne` function doesn't works. i.e.,

> **the output of `wrongOne` = the output of `correctOne` + []byte{"Copyright 2022 Company Inc... Success."}**

Is there any solution that I can get the `output_file.avi` in the pipe without save it as file and read it from disk? Thanks!

Comment: the quick hack is : `output = bytes.TrimSuffix(output, []byte{"Copyright 2022 Company Inc... Sucess"})` (possibly with a `"\n"` somewhere)

Comment: @LeGEC sadly, the verbose information will contain certain information related to the input, trim with static string won't work since it changes from time to time :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The command writes the copyright notice to stdout. To avoid commingling the copyright notice with the output file, use a file other than /dev/stdout as the output file.

The function below uses [Cmd.ExtraFiles](https://pkg.go.dev/os/exec#Cmd.ExtraFiles) to connect a [pipe](https://pkg.go.dev/os#Pipe) to fd 3 in the child process.  The function copies data from the pipe to a byte buffer and returns those bytes to the caller.

```
func otherOne(stdin []byte) ([]byte, error) {
    r, w, err := os.Pipe()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    defer r.Close()
    defer w.Close()

    cmd := exec.Command("./my_bin", "/dev/stdin", "/dev/fd/3")
    cmd.Stdin = bytes.NewReader(stdin)
    cmd.ExtraFiles = []*os.File{w} // The first file is fd 3.
    if err := cmd.Start(); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    w.Close()
    var outbuf bytes.Buffer
    if _, err := io.Copy(&outbuf, r); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    if err := cmd.Wait(); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return outbuf.Bytes(), nil
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. Here's another question: is this function thread-safe? We may have several requests to call this program at the same time. Will they have conflicts on writing/reading something like `/dev/fd/3` or `/dev/stdin`?

Comment: @WillZhao: `exec.Command(...)` will create a whole new *process*, `/dev/stdin` and `/dev/fd/3` is defined for each process. So yes : you can run these concurrently.

Answer (score 0):

After months, I figure out another way to solve this problem. The basic idea is similar with [Cerise](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5728991/cerise-lim%c3%b3n), i.e., using `/dev/fd/3` to redirect the output file. After that, we redirect `/dev/fd/3` to `/dev/stdout`, verbose log to `/dev/stderr`
by `3>&1`, `1>&2`, respectively. An additional `gen.sh` is added. Here's the solution:

```bash
#gen.sh
./mybin /dev/stdin /dev/fd/3 3>&1 1>&2
```

```golang
// gen.go
func gen(stdin []byte) ([]byte, error) {
    inBuf := bytes.NewBuffer(stdin)
    outBuf := bytes.NewBuffer(nil)
    cmd := exec.Command("./gen.sh")
    cmd.Stdin = inBuf
    cmd.Stdout = outBuf
    cmd.Stderr = os.Stderr
    err := cmd.Run()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return outBuf.Bytes(), nil
}
```